# How to count the number of charts in a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to count the number of charts in a worksheet, called "PROC MONTAGE", upon opening the Excel file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Worksheets("PROC MONTAGE").Cells(4, 14) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PROC MONTAGE").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

End Sub
```

It returns

> Error 1004, defined by application or Object

How do I solve this, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: ChartObjects.Count. ChartObjects is the collection of chart objects.

Comment: To expand on @Barry comment:  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PROC MONTAGE").ChartObjects.Count`

Comment: Or you can loop through all shape objects and count all shape objects of type chart.

Comment: Thank you @Barry and Darren Bartup-Cook
I tried it and it works.